# Typescript outputs "class" identifier into javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

So... I've been using typescript today and using typescript classes, example class (actually the one that throws the error, only because it's the first one in the outputted js file)

```
class AuthRequestDTO {
    grant_type: string;
    refresh_token: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    client_id: string;
    use_refresh: boolean;
}
```

This is in a .ts file, along with many other .ts files in the project. the project is set to compile all ts files into 1 output js file, this works fine. Now onto the issue; When I try and browse to my site in chrome, firefox or IE they all throw an exception saying "class is a reserved identifier". yet the class identifier in a Typescript file is perfectly valid. Why is typescript outputting the class keyword into the resultant .js file? (I understand that class is a reserved identifier in javascript, that's not my concern, my concern is why is Visual Studio 2015s TS Compiler putting the "class" keyword into the output?) Is there a setting i've missed, or something that Visual Studio has been smoking today?

**What i've tried so far and what im using:**

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, Solution is on ES6, TS Build options into single .js file. I'm also using AngularJs libraries with typings and JQuery with Typings if any of you feel using those libraries is a contributing factor. I've also cleaned and rebuilt the project and the entire solution and restarted my development machine too. I have also turned off the "Combine javascript output into file" setting to see if it was something quirky with that and i come across the same issue in seperate .js files so it's not that. forcing "use strict" also doesn't help, that was a farfetched attempt though because that's a Javascript command and not a typescript one but thought i'd try it anyway.

Comment: What have you selected for your ECMAScript version in the `Project Properties > TypeScript Build`? Because if it's `EMCAScript 6`, `class` is a valid identifer but is not supported by (most) browsers. If you want it to run in a browser you need to pick `ECMAScript 5` as the target

Comment: The solution is set for ES 6. Does this mean that ES6 is too bleeding edge for most browsers at the moment?

Comment: Correct. You can check ES6 Browser Compatibility [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: Excellent, changing ES Version to 5 has got it working - Recent upgrade to VS2015 must have changed the default. please post an answer to use ES5 instead of ES6 so I can mark as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Typescript outputs “class” identifier into javascript

If you have your compile target set to `es6`, then TypeScript will not downlevel emit `class`.

Set your compile Target to `es5` to have `class` transpiled to `function/prototype` pattern.